# Postgres: optimizing join with a many-many relationship table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-15

I have a query I'm trying to optimize and am running into some surprising/perplexing results.

The tables I'm working with are features and areas, each of which have their own ids and geometries.

```sql
                            Table "features"
   Column    |  Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | bigint   |           | not null | 
 category    | text     |           | not null | 
 geom        | geometry |           | not null | 

Indexes:
    "features_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "features_category_idx" btree (category)

                            Table "areas"
   Column    |  Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | bigint   |           | not null | 
 geom        | geometry |           | not null | 

Indexes:
    "features_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The next table stores the many-many relationship between `features` and `areas`, with foreign key constraints. Each features may be in zero, one, or many areas (if they're in no areas, they have no entries in the `feature_area` table) and each area has many features.

```sql
                        Table "feature_area"
   Column     |    Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 feature_id   | bigint   |           | not null | 
 area_id      | bigint   |           | not null | 
 category     | text     |           |          | 

Indexes:
    "feature_area_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (feature_id, area_id)
    "feature_area_category_idx" btree (category)

Foreign-key constraints:
    "feature_area_feature_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feature_id) REFERENCES features(feature_id)
    "feature_area_area_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areas(area_id)
```

What I'm trying to get to is a result like this - all features of category `type_x` that have fall within any areas:

```sql
  feature_id   |    areas    |    geom    
---------------+-------------+-------------
  1            | {45,123}    | xxxxxx
  3            | {8}         | xxxxxx
```

Here's the query I'm working on. It's very slow (~35 seconds).

```sql
-- QUERY 1

WITH area_type_x AS (
  SELECT 
    feature_id,
    array_agg(area_id) AS areas
  FROM feature_area
  WHERE category = 'long name for type x'
  GROUP BY feature_id
)
SELECT
  features.id feature_id,
  features.geom,
  area_type_x.areas
FROM area_type_x
JOIN features ON features.id = area_type_x.feature_id;
```

By chance, I tried this, and it's much faster (<3 seconds).

```sql
-- QUERY 2

WITH area_type_x AS (
  SELECT 
    feature_id,
    array_agg(area_id) AS areas
  FROM feature_area
  WHERE short_name(category) = 'type_x' -- this line is the only difference
  GROUP BY feature_id
)
SELECT
  features.id feature_id,
  features.geom,
  area_type_x.areas
FROM area_type_x
JOIN features ON features.id = area_type_x.feature_id;
```

I ran each with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and can share those results if it's helpful, but haven't been able to make sense of them myself.

Any idea what's going on? I'd like to figure it out, because I suspect that I may be able to do better than the 3 seconds, if I can skip converting `category` to its short version, but keep whatever improvements its giving me.

#### EDIT/UPDATE:

I have some additional information. Based on a handful of articles/SO questions, I temporarily set `enable_seqscan=off`. This drastically changed the runtime of my query. Query 1 now takes just a little less time to run than Query 2, which makes more sense to me. The change seems to be in the query plan.

Query 1, with `enable_seqscan=on`, takes >30 seconds:

```sql
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=114638.13..481900.52 rows=881850 width=169) (actual time=7136.629..33748.990 rows=884251 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=113638.13..392715.52 rows=367438 width=169) (actual time=7172.678..32326.371 rows=294750 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (features.id = area_type_x.feature_id)
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on features  (cost=0.00..159192.80 rows=2589180 width=137) (actual time=12.512..778.814 rows=2057905 loops=3)
         ->  Hash  (cost=95725.00..95725.00 rows=881850 width=40) (actual time=7061.588..7061.591 rows=884251 loops=3)
               Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 4915kB
               ->  Subquery Scan on area_type_x  (cost=0.43..95725.00 rows=881850 width=40) (actual time=116.879..1422.959 rows=884251 loops=3)
                     ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..86906.50 rows=881850 width=40) (actual time=116.877..1333.640 rows=884251 loops=3)
                           Group Key: feature_area.feature_id
                           ->  Index Scan using feature_area_pkey on feature_area  (cost=0.43..71341.84 rows=908307 width=16) (actual time=116.808..803.575 rows=905628 loops=3)
                                 Filter: (category = 'long name for type x'::text)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 228763
 Planning Time: 0.577 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 48
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 10.385 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.417 ms, Emission 33.150 ms, Total 45.952 ms
 Execution Time: 33796.604 ms
(20 rows)
```

Query 1, with `enable_seqscan=off`, takes roughly 3 sec:

```sql
                                                      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=0.86..860907.04 rows=881850 width=169) (actual time=1288.916..3362.281 rows=884251 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (feature_area.feature_id = features.id)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..86906.50 rows=881850 width=40) (actual time=179.721..865.900 rows=884251 loops=1)
         Group Key: feature_area.feature_id
         ->  Index Scan using feature_area_pkey on feature_area  (cost=0.43..71341.84 rows=908307 width=16) (actual time=179.686..550.355 rows=905628 loops=1)
               Filter: (category = 'long name for type x'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 228763
   ->  Index Scan using features_pkey on features  (cost=0.43..738623.83 rows=6214031 width=137) (actual time=0.095..2033.808 rows=5979584 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.577 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 12
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.839 ms, Inlining 10.214 ms, Optimization 67.773 ms, Emission 38.734 ms, Total 118.561 ms
 Execution Time: 3389.080 ms
(14 rows)
```

Turning `enable_seqscan` off for a production database clearly isn't an option. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a CTE:

```
SELECT
  features.id feature_id,
  features.geom,
  array_agg(area_id) AS areas
FROM feature_area
JOIN features ON features.id = feature_area.feature_id
WHERE category = 'long name for type x'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The problem with the CTE is it calculates the aggregation of areas for *all* features, but calculating the aggregation *after* the join only does that work for the features you need.

Also, the result of the CTE has to live somewhere and storing a large amount of data (memory, possibly temporarily disk space) is another source of query expense.

Comment: This query has pretty similar performance to the very slow one I posted in my question. Your reasoning makes perfect sense to me and I'm completely perplexed by why it would be so slow. If I replace the `WHERE` clause from your query with `WHERE short_name(categeory) = 'type_x'`, I get much improved performance. Which doesn't make sense to me, since there's actually an index on the `category` field in both `features` and `feature_area`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't define a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/indexes-functional.html) on `short_name(category)`? Can you alter the category column to be type `varchar(n)` (making n small as possible)? Then redefine the index on it?